# Installing 32 bit libraries on arch linux

Tags: linux, 32bit-64bit, arch-linux

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.
So far I've figured out that I need to add (uncomment)

```
[multilib]  
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

On "/etc/pacman.conf" and then run:

```
sudo pacman-key --init
```

When I run:

```
sudo pacman -S
```

I get:

```
warning: database file for 'multilib' does not exist
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refresh the package list first after adding repos: `pacman -Syy`

Regarding `pacman-key --init`: you can set up pacman for the use with signed packages. By default pacman will accept unsigned packages. So this step is optional and also requires further steps. Refer to the arch wiki for the whole process: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_package_signing

Comment: OK, that solved the warning... How do I actually install the 32bit lib?

Comment: As you install every other package `pacman -S package_name`

Answer (score 2):

You can search for packages named lib32 with: `pacman -Ss lib32`